# Saving a MATLAB matrix as an image to a specific size and resolution

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, file-io

After having read [this](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/47357-save-figure-in-a-certain-size) question, I wanted to use this code to save my picture as to particular size.

```
    I_c(:,:) = cropped_matrix(i,:,:);
    set(I_c, 'PaperUnits', 'inches');
    x_width = 7.25;
    y_width = 9.125;
    set(I_c, 'PaperPosition', [0 0 x_width y_width]);
    imshow(I_c);
    saveas(I_c,'fig1.pdf');
```

`I_c` represents a 2D matrix (about 40x40) of `uint8`'s.

However, I get the error:

> Error using set Invalid handle

This makes me believe that I can only use this code with figures and not matrices which contain matrices. How would I go about this?

I have looked at the [API](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html#inputarg_formatoptions) for `print`, as suggested as the first answer of the aforementioned linked question, but it also suggests using `set` and `'PaperUnits'`.

Note: [This](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102382-how-do-i-specify-the-output-sizes-of-jpeg-png-and-tiff-images-when-using-the-print-function-in-mat) question also looks at this problem but suggests the same solution.

---

**Notes About Crowley's Answer**

1. So I just tried the code that you have given with your answer. The `.jpg` being produced is the one shown below. How would I get rid of all the extra white area through code?
2. How would I change the `colourmap` of the figure being produced, to greyscale when I just use `image(ImData)`?

[image]

And here is how the actual figure appears:

[image]

Here is the code that I have put in:

```
 im = image(I_c); 
 set(gcf,'units','inches','position',[1 2 5 5]);
 set(gca,'ydir','normal','units','centimeters','position',[0 0 0.5 0.5].*get(gcf,'position')) ;
 filename = strcat('slice',int2str(i),'_','bead',int2str(j),'.jpg');
 saveas(im,filename);
```

Comment: If you have the image processing toolbox then you can use [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html?refresh=true). Otherwise you'll have to do it manually using `interp2`. `set` is expecting the first variable to be a handle to a figure or axes, it will not work on a matrix.

Comment: I struggle to understand the meaning of the variables. `I_dw` seems to be your image, but you never use it. `I_c` could be a handle to a figure, but that does not match the use of `imshow;`.

Comment: For the record though, there is no point posting an error clearly caused by the variable `I_c` without giving any context for what `I_c` is...

Comment: @Daniel Just made the change to the code.

Comment: @Dan added a description of what `I_c` is.

Comment: @Dan Could yo elaborate on how I could use `interp2` here

Comment: @SharanDuggirala cropped matrix is a single row? Is the third dimension RGB or is your image just permuted to be in weird dimensions? When saving an image, you are only saving the number of pixels, Inches has nothing to do with it. If you know off hand what your printed DPI will be, then you can decide on your pixel resolution based on that and use `interp2` to resize the image in terms of number of pixels.

Comment: @Dan I'm using greyscale. So the images will only be of two dimensions. If you can write the code down for how to achieve this with `interp2`, I will accept your answer!

Comment: Maybe using `set(gcf,'units','centimeters','position',[0 0 width, height])` and  `set(gca,'units','centimeters','position',get(gcf,'position'))` should create figure with given size without borders.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala: `I_c` is not the handle to your figure. It is your image data. Start with `h=figure` and use this handle for `get` `set` and `saveas`

Comment: @Daniel how would I create a figure of my image?

Comment: @Crowley Could you please try that with an image and see if it works. If it does, add that as an answer.

Comment: Could You provide a screenshot of Your matlab figure?

Comment: @Crowley I put up the figure too

Comment: Have You changed `units` and `position` in BOTH `gcf` and `gca`?

Comment: @Crowley The exact code that I have used has also been put into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have matrix `I_c` containing values and `x` and `y` the coordinates so value `I_c(ii,jj)` corresponds to `x(ii)` and `y(jj)` coordinates.

Then:

```
ImMin=min(min(I_c));    % Find the minimum value in I_c
ImData=I_c-ImMin;       % Ensure non-zero values
ImMax=max(max(ImData)); % Find maximum value in ImData
ImData=ImData./ImMax;   % Ensure ImData do NOT exceed 1

image(x,y,ImData*[1 1 1]) % plot the image in greyscale
set(gcf,'units','inches','position',[1 2 5 5]) % set active figure properties
set(gca,'ydir','normal','units','inches','position',[0 0 1 1].*get(gcf,'position')) % set active axes properties

export_fig(gcf,'figure-I_c','-png','-nocrop')
```

`'ydir','normal'` parameter change default (1,1) point being in top-left corner to "normal" position in bottom-left corner.
`[0 0 1 1].*get(gcf,'position)` will read active figure position (here [1 2 5 5]) and after element-by-element multiplication the `[0 0 5 5]` is passed to the `position` which causes that axes fit the image.

`export_fig` function will create `figure-I_c.png` image as it is shown in Matlab figure, if `-nocrop` is omitted the possible white space in the edges is cropped out. This function is available from [MathWorks' File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig).

Comment: You can also use `image(ImData)` and then choose a colourmap to fit your needs.

Comment: let's say I use `image(Imdata)`, how would I chose the colourmap?

Comment: Hey, I've added a section to the question to reflect my implementation of your answer. Please check it out!

Comment: For colormap just type `help image` in Your matlab shell. You can also get more ingo by clicking `doc image` at the end of the returned text.

Comment: Just looked at the API for `image`, there seems to be no option of changing the colormapping to one ranging from black to pure white instead of blue and yellow.

Comment: I have changed the `'units','centimetres'` to `'units','inches'` - the have to be the same. I'm used to metric system but You use imperial. to avoid this You ca use `'units',get(gcf,'units')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104523/discussion-between-crowley-and-sharan-duggirala).

Comment: Hey, if you flesh out your answer with everything we discussed, I'll accept it as the correct answer!